# .save throws an error instead of execute the else part of the conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Validation for uniqueness applies to a combination of two fields. My problem is that patching a new record that does validate, throws the error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`, rather than that it executes the `else` part of the method below. Why does it throw an error instead of execute the else part? How to change this?

```
def create
  first_node = Node.find_by(id: params[:first_node_id])
  second_node = Node.find_by(id: params[:second_node_id])
  link = first_node.where_first_links.build(create_params)
  if link.save
    render json: link, status: :created
  else
    render json: link, message: "unable", status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

In the migration file:

```
add_index :links, [:first_node_id, :second_node_id], unique: true
```

The model validation:

```
before_save  :order_nodes
validates :first_node_id,    presence: true
validates :second_node_id,   presence: true
validates :first_node_id,    uniqueness: { scope: :second_node_id } 

def order_nodes
  if first_node_id > second_node_id
    first = first_node_id
    second = second_node_id
    self.first_node_id  = second
    self.second_node_id = first
    if direction == '0'
      self.direction = 1
    elsif direction == '1'
      self.direction = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most probably means that:

- Your object passed the validation.
- THEN your before_save callback reordered the fields
- Subsequent attempt to save the record to the database violated the database unique constraint

Try changing your callback from:

```
before_save  :order_nodes
```

to:

```
before_validation  :order_nodes
```

NOTE: In this case, you'll have to assume that your fields may be invalid and rewrite your callback accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Perfect explanation also!